# Load different CSS based on user device in Google Script Web App

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

Edited for more clarity:

I have a simple Google Script / Web App project but simply cannot figure out how to load a different CSS file based on the user device.

IE. I am not trying to implement responsive design, due to certain requirement I need to load a different CSS file based on the user device.

I have setup the following:

Index.html | css1.html | css2.html

I have the following code in my head in Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <? if (/Mobi/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {?>
            <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('css1').getContent(); ?>
          <?} else {?>
            <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('css2').getContent(); ?>
          <?}?>
      </head>
      <body>
         <p> THIS is a TEST </p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

When I deploy and test the above I get: ReferenceError: navigator is not defined (line 5)

I got the code from [How to detect mobile user with Google App Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229683/how-to-detect-mobile-user-with-google-app-script)

The code at the above link works when deployed as a page and called via

```
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('test').getContent(); ?>
```

I tried different approach such as @media load but nothing seems to work. I can load different pages based on the user device, which I could use as a workaround without issue but I'd prefer it to be a CSS.

--> Edit: code.gs

```
function doGet(e) 
{
    var html      = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');  
    var pageData  = html.evaluate()
                    .setTitle('Web App 1')                        
                    .setFaviconUrl('https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/product/2x/apps_script_64dp.png')
                    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)                             // This method now has no effect — previously it set the sandbox mode used for client-side scripts
                    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')              // It is very important tag for Responsive design
                    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)               // Sets the state of the page's X-Frame-Options header, which controls clickjacking prevention.
    return pageData;
}
function include(filename)
{
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
        .getContent();
};
```

--> css1.html

```
<style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>

p {
  color: blue;
}

</style>
```

--> css2.html

```
<style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>

p {
  color: red;
}

</style>
```

For @Media I tried the following in the `<head>` but it did not work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 140px) and (max-width: 380px)' href="css1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 381px) and (max-width: 700px)' href="css2"/>
```

Comment: In order to correctly replicate your issue of `ReferenceError: navigator is not defined`, can you provide the current script for loading your HTML template? By the way, if you are actually using `HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('body1').getContent()`, I think that your HTML template is not correctly used. Please check the official document of the HTML template. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) Unfortunately, I cannot know your actual script. So, I cannot still propose the modified script. I apologize for this.

Comment: Add `css1` and your attempt at `@media`

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed 2 sample modifications. Please confirm it. If those were not useful, I apologize. By the way, it seems that in your added CSS, <style> is not correctly enclosed. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Your `css1.html` doesn't seem to be valid. `<style>` is present twice, but `</style>` just once.

Comment: DOH, wow, yes, precisely. Thank you so much. I feel... Well, thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your showing script, I think that `navigator.userAgent` is Javascript which is not Google Apps Script. In this case, in order to select CSS by the value of `navigator.userAgent`, as one approach, I thought the following flow.

1. Retrieve the value of `navigator.userAgent` when HTML is opened.
2. Send the value of `navigator.userAgent` to Google Apps Script.
3. At the Google Apps Script side, the selected CSS is returned.

When this flow is reflected in a simple sample script, how about the following sample script?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, google.script.run is used.

#### HTML & Javascript side:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">

  <script>
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {
    console.log(e); // Here, you can check the returned CSS at the console.
    document.querySelector("head").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', e); // or 'afterBegin'
  }).getStyle(/Mobi/.test(navigator.userAgent))
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  sample
</body>

</html>
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
const getStyle = e => HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(e ? 'css1' : 'css2').getContent();

function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
  var pageData = html
    .setTitle('Web App 1')
    .setFaviconUrl('https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/product/2x/apps_script_64dp.png')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
  return pageData;
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, an HTML template is used. In this case, when the HTML is opened, both CSS files are included. And, one of them is used by `navigator.userAgent`.

#### HTML & Javascript side:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">

  <script>
    const css1 = `<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('css1').getContent(); ?>`;
    const css2 = `<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('css2').getContent(); ?>`;
    document.querySelector("head").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', /Mobi/.test(navigator.userAgent) ? css1 : css2); // or 'afterBegin'
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  sample
</body>

</html>
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  var pageData = html.evaluate()
    .setTitle('Web App 1')
    .setFaviconUrl('https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/product/2x/apps_script_64dp.png')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
  return pageData;
}
```

### Note:

- This is a simple script. If you use this script, please modify this for your actual situation.
- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: Thanks. I'm studying your solution but am currently not able to implement it. IE. the "sample" text does not change color according to the CSS files. I guess I am not doing something correctly, at the moment I cannot figure out what that is but hope to get there. I tried both solutions and the console log does not show what file was selected when I checked, it just says completed successfully

Comment: Do I change beforeend string to something else? Not sure what it means. Thank you.